# Status: 500 Internal Server Error While running Post

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create an ESN and save it in my database
I'm using Nodejs and Mongodb
you can find the model, route and controller that I have created, what I want is a simple POST API to add an ESN to my data base.

Models

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const esnSchema = new Schema({
  esnName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  esnEmail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  esnLogo: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String,
    required: false,
  }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Esn",esnSchema);
```

Controllers

```
const Esn = require('../models/esn');

// create new ESN
const createEsn = async (req, res) => {
    
  if (!req.body.esnName) {
    res.status(400).send({ message:   "Content can not be empty!" });
    return;
  }
  const esn = new Esn({
        esnName: req.body.esnName,
        esnEmail: req.body.esnEmail,
       esnLogo: req.body.esnLogo
      });

  // Save Esn in the database
  esn
    .save(esn)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error      occurred while creating the esn"
      });
    });
};
    
module.exports = {
    createEsn
  };
```

Routes

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const esnSchema = new Schema({
  esnName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  esnEmail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  esnLogo: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String,
    required: false,
  }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Esn",esnSchema);
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express'),
cors = require('cors'),
swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express'),
swaggerDocument = require('./docs/swagger.json');
const Mongo = require('mongodb');
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const mainRoutes = require('./routes/esn')

const app = express();
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";
var databasename = "skills";

Mongo.MongoClient.connect(url).then((client) => {
console.log('Database connected');
const connect = client.db(databasename);
//const collection = connect.createCollection("esn");
console.log('Database: ', connect);
}).catch((err) => {
// Handling the error
console.log(err.Message);
})

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Listening on port 3000!');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('Hello World');
});

app.use('/api/', mainRoutes);

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

I expected to save an esn in the database but I have this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPzwM.png)

Comment: Can you please provide log of `req.body` in controller? And try to save API by commenting `esnLogo: req.body.esnLogo` so that you can understand where is problem.

Comment: Did you successful connect to the database? Post your full terminal output from the node app.

Comment: @ArifKhan 
I commented esnLogo: req.body.esnLogo
the log of req.body is : { esnName: 'test', esnEmail: 'test@test.be' }

Comment: @Marc
Normally I connected to the database

Comment: @FawzyOTHMAN The error messages says something else.

Comment: @Marc
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Listening on port 3000!
Database connected
Database:  Db {
  s: {
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      mongoLogger: [MongoLogger],
      s: [Object],
      topology: [Topology],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },

Comment: @Marc
 options: {
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      logger: [Logger],
      pkFactory: [Object],
      raw: false,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      retryWrites: true
    },
    logger: Logger { className: 'Db' },
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },

Comment: @Marc
bsonOptions: {
      raw: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {},
      enableUtf8Validation: true
    },
    pkFactory: { createPk: [Function: createPk] },
    readConcern: undefined,
    writeConcern: undefined,
    namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'skills', collection: undefined }
  }
}

Comment: here the full terminal output..